# Needle in a Haystack for Php

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I need to make a needle in a haystack program using a one dimensional array, so that when the user types in their input the script searches through table and the array till it finds the needle and displays its location. I'm new to programming and confused as to how to get to  that point.

```
<?php
 $haystack = array('cs85','cs60','cs61', 'cs80', 'cs81');
 $js = $_REQUEST['js'];
 $php = $_REQUEST['php'];
 $net = $_REQUEST['net'];
 $int = $_REQUEST['int'];
 $data = $_REQUEST['data'];

if(!array_search($needle, $haystack)) {
    echo $needle."Needle Not Found";
}else{
    echo $needle. "Needle Found!";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Find needle in haystack</title>
<style type = "text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Find the Needle in the Haystack</h1>
<table>
    <h1>Haystack</h1>
<tr class = 'php'><td>php</td></tr>
<tr class = 'js'><td>javascript</td></tr>
<tr class = 'int'><td>intermediate</td></tr>
<tr class = 'net'><td>Network</td></tr>
<tr class = 'data'><td>Data</td></tr>
</table>
   <form method = 'get'>
       <label>Needle:
          <input type = "textbox" name = "needle" id = "needle" value = "break">
        </label>
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could start by defining `$needle`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/) is an excellent reference for such, please take a look at that before posting questions like this!

here is what you may need to change in your code:

```
// Set a name attribute for the submit button
<input type = "submit" value = "submit" name="submit">


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      // setup variables
      $haystack = array('cs85','cs60','cs61', 'cs80', 'cs81');
      $needle = strip_tags($_POST['needle']);

      if(!array_search($needle, $haystack)) {
        echo $needle. " Needle Not Found";
      } else {
        echo $needle. " Needle Found!";
      }
    }
?>
```

[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_search.asp) has a nice example about a similar search.

[Check this out](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) for more details